# How does Chapel handle "includes"

Tags: compilation, chapel

Now, if I have two Chapel projects `ProjA` and `ProjB`.

If I want to use `ProjA` in `B`, I include the `-M/path/to/ProjA` flag in my [makefile](/questions/tagged/makefile).  In [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) however, the paradigm is often to include whole libraries, like `boost`, that are install system-wide.  What is the analog to this in Chapel.  Is there a `chpl --compile-as-system-library` flag or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the analog to this in Chapel. Is there a chpl --compile-as-system-library flag or something?

If I'm understanding correctly, you can accomplish this by setting [`CHPL_MODULE_PATH`](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/master/technotes/module_search.html) to a designated common library path, and putting the Chapel modules into that directory. This will remove the constraint of adding `-M` flags to all your compilations, e.g.

```
> export CHPL_MODULE_PATH=/path/to/ProjA
> chpl B.chpl
```

In the long term, Mason won't solve this problem exactly. According to current design plans, Mason will only manage dependencies on a package basis, so it won't have the ability to make packages available system-wide without specifying the dependencies in the package manifest file.